# How does the onDraw(Canvas) function of the View class work?

Tags: android, canvas

I need to implement an interactive graph in Android
For a start I am trying to see [how this code works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7362757/1693203)
There, in a class called LineChartView Which extends the user generated class ChartView which extends the View class, there is an `@override`ed function called `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`. How and when does this function get called? the output of that code is a bunch of graphs on full screen, but my interactive graph should only take up a part of the screen. Does the onDraw() function get called automatically? If so, when? And what is the size of the canvas? Is it always the full screen occupied by the current activity's window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this link [View Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) there is a section on implementing a custom view

onDraw(Canvas canvas) is called whenever a view should render its content

if you define to use this view in your layout xml or even in code you can specify the attributes

```
android:layout_width=
android:layout_height=
```

and those attributes will be applied to the size that the view will use

in your layout.xml

```
<your.package.name.extendedviewclass
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

Comment: So from what I have understood till now, I need to create a class that extends View, and this class represents the view in which I should be drawing my graph. This class should have an overridden onDraw(), that gets called whenever the view needs to get updated. Is this how it works? How do I specify the size and location of this extended View class? In some of the sample codes that I am reading they don't specify any of these, but the output takes up the full screen. So is the size and position the full screen by default, or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah like that, i just put edit how you define a custom view in xml

Comment: and you can position and arrange the different views just like any other views in your xml, i think thats the easiest way

Comment: so all the logic related to my graph should go to the onDraw() method of this extended view class? And what about the coordinate system inside this view? Does it have it's own coordinate axes, or do I have to use the main screen's absolute coordinate axes?

Comment: if you override protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) method in your extended view just like onDraw() that will give you the width and height of the view, and the canvas is the background of the view and since the view is the width and height than the background is also the width and height, and you can use any logic youd like to add up to the onDraw even touches of the view if youd like